# Send mail not working in Spring/Maven/Java 6 environment

Tags: java, spring, maven

I am using java 6.0, Spring 3.0 & Maven. I am facing a strange problem.

I am trying to send mail from my application, but not able to do so. I checked with debug on, the logs seems fine - no exception/error but the mail doesn't trigger.

Relevant code:

```
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.RecipientType;

public class JavaEmail 
{
    private final String SMTP_AUTH_USER = "admin@myorg.com";
    private final String SMTP_AUTH_PWD  = "secret";

    public void sendMain(String strFrom, String strTo, String strSubject, String    
strContent) throws MessagingException 
    {
        Message message = new MimeMessage(getSession());

        message.addRecipient(RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(strTo));
        message.addFrom(new InternetAddress[] { new InternetAddress(strFrom)});

        message.setSubject(strSubject);
        message.setContent(strContent, "text/plain");

        try {
            Transport.send(message);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private Session getSession() {
        Authenticator authenticator = new Authenticator();

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.submitter", 
authenticator.getPasswordAuthentication().getUserName());
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.myorg.com");
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "25");
        properties.setProperty("mail.debug", "true");

        return Session.getInstance(properties, authenticator);
    }

    private class Authenticator extends javax.mail.Authenticator 
    {
        private PasswordAuthentication authentication;

        public Authenticator() 
        {
            String username = SMTP_AUTH_USER;
            String password = SMTP_AUTH_PWD;
            authentication = new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
        }

        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() 
        {
            return authentication;
        }
    }


    public static void main (String [] args) throws MessagingException {

        JavaEmail email = new JavaEmail();

        email.sendMain("myid@myorg.com", "myid@myorg.com", "Say Hi ..", "Body");

    }

}
```

**POM (relevant):**

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

**Logs:**

```
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.myorg.com", port 25, isSSL false
220 droutbound.logix.in ESMTP
DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "smtp.myorg.com", port: 25

EHLO ABCDE1234
250-droutbound.logix.in
250-8BITMIME
250-SIZE 26214400
250-STARTTLS
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250 AUTH=PLAIN LOGIN
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "26214400"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "STARTTLS", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH", arg "PLAIN LOGIN"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH=PLAIN", arg "LOGIN"
DEBUG SMTP: Attempt to authenticate
AUTH LOGIN
334 VXNl1cm25hbW2U6
c2NjYWRta1W5Ae3mVuc42Fy5Lmlu
334 UGFz7c63dv2cmQ6
WmVuc22Fy5MT7IzIw==
235 #2.0.0 OK Authenticated
DEBUG SMTP: use8bit false
MAIL FROM:&lt;address@myorg.com&gt; AUTH=address@myorg.com
250 sender &lt;address@myorg.com&gt; ok
RCPT TO:&lt;address@myorg.com&gt;
250 recipient &lt;address@myorg.com&gt; ok
DEBUG SMTP: Verified Addresses
DEBUG SMTP:   address@myorg.com
DATA
354 go ahead

Body
.
250 ok:  Message 325177010 accepted
QUIT
221 droutbound.logix.in
```

I have tried with other sample programs as well - with or without spring configurations. No error. BUT no mail as well.

**IMP** - same program(s) work fine if I use them in my other project which doesn't use maven - but otherwise have same configurations. 
In those logs there are some more lines in between ..

```
**DATA
354 go ahead
From: address@myorg.com
To: address@myorg.com
Message-ID: &lt;12694833.01327427956033.JavaMail.myid@ABCDE12345&gt;
Subject: Say Hi ..
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Body
.**
```

I am stuck. Is this due to Maven? Please suggest.

Comment: How about posting the relevant pom snippet?  Perhaps you have a missing runtime jar.

Comment: I have put relevant pom snippet, its in code section. Here it is again :

Comment: <dependency>
   <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
   <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
   <version>1.4.1</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: If you use java 5 (not java 6) for the runtime, you will need the java activation framework too.

But if you have the feeling that maven is the problem, then check that the jar is only once in you application. (`com.springsource.javax.mail` for example is the same content)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it was more than required jars that were causing issue.

On extracting my war - I noticed there are below jars:

geronimo-activation_1.1_spec-1.0.1.jar, geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec-1.2.jar, geronimo-jta_1.1_spec-1.1.jar, geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec-1.0.1.jar etc.

There is no entry for them in my pom - these are being included in my lib due to some other dependency. So, below did work ..

```
<plugin>
<artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.1.1</version>
<configuration>
<packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/web.xml,WEB-INF/lib/geronimo-activation_1.1_spec-   
        1.0.1.jar, WEB-INF/lib/geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec-1.2.jar
</packagingExcludes>
<warName>SCTM_Retailer</warName>
</configuration>
</plugin>
```

Thanks Ralph & Raghuram.

Comment: Thank you, this helped finding the problem.
By the way, you could have just used dependencyManagement to exclude them in a more neat (maven-ish) way